# Hibernate: How to reason about Optimistic Locking Exception under contention / high concurrency?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, concurrency

I have the following structure in my database via Hibernate. I am operating on MySQL. This structure is a table with a simple counter describing how often (column **count**) an event happens per day (column **day**).

```
@Entity
@Table(name="daily_log")
public class DailyLog {
    @Version
    @Column(name="opt_lock_v")
    protected Integer version;

    @Column(name="day")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date day;

    @Column(name="count")
    private Integer count;
}
```

In my application, I simply perform the following operation for an increment:

```
DailyLog log = dailyLogRepository.findLogEntry(new Date()); // get row by current day
log.setCount(log.getCount() + 1); // increment count by 1
```

And later in my application, I read from the database the updated count i.e. `log.getCount()`.

Under high load/ high contention, the code which updates the counter throws an `OptimisticLockException` which is a problem from Hibernate's versioning mechanism.

How can I avoid such concurrency issues? Is it safe to delegate concurrency management to MySQL rather than to Hibernate? Would it make sense to implement a trigger or view and let the DBMS handle the concurrency?

Another option I was thinking about is asynchronous database write/update, but since I need to later read this counter, I do need some guarantee that the DBMS has successfully made an update, so I'm not sure if asynchronous operation is a solution. For clarification, If I send an update command to my DBMS, I would like to read this update, but I do not want to have blocking operations which could decrease my throughput.

**At the end of the day, I want to perform a simple increment, maintain high throughput, avoid concurrency issues and read the most updated counter I can possibly read.**

I am very new to Hibernate so apologies if question is not clear.

Comment: You can write an update that does this in one statement, instead of finding and saving in 2 steps.

Comment: Sure, but how will this affect concurrency issues and throughput? I would appreciate any comment in this regard.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 that suggestion fixed the problem - but why? Could you please help me understand? In other words, I changed from "set" method to "update" DML.

Comment: If you do things in 2 steps some other thread can interfere in between. If you do it in 1 step you’re safe.

Comment: @NathanHughes台湾不在中国 In my update statement, I am no longer making use of "opt_lock_v" (@Version), maybe that is why I do not get OptimisticLockException anymore? If so, will I get correctness problems?